# Responsive left fly-out menu

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, mobile

I am working on [this website](http://thehotdeal.net/clients/1/chris/re/phase3/) currently.

If you resize the window to less than 650px then the main menu is replaced by a button which when pressed triggers a left fly-out menu similar to the Facebook uses on the mobile website.

When viewed on a computer the menu works very well, but on mobile devices the performance is not so good and the slide-in effect is not smooth.  I need help with the performance.

```
<!-- Mobile Nav.. the navigation items are generated dynamically using jQuery -->
<div id="mobNav" style="background: url(images/top_bg.jpg) repeat; background-size: 100%; position:absolute; left:-200px; width:200px; height:100%;">

</div>

 <!--  This is just a wrapper for the rest of the page content -->
 <div id="shift">
      content Goes Here
 </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     var mobNav    = $("#mobNav"),
         mainNav   = $("#mainnav"),
         top       = $("#top"),
         shift     = $("#shift");
     // add navigation items to mobile nav
     mobNav.html(mainNav.html());

     $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 300){
          top.fadeIn();
        } else{
          top.fadeOut();
        }
        if(parseInt(mobNav.css("left"), 10) == 0){
          // if is visible then hide
          mobNav.css("left", -mobNav.outerWidth());
          shift.css("margin-left", "0");
        }
      });

      $(window).on("resize", function() {
        if(parseInt(mobNav.css("left"), 10) == 0){
          // if is visible then hide
          mobNav.css("left", -mobNav.outerWidth());
          shift.css("margin-left", "0");
        }
      });
      // button that triggers mobile nav visibility
      $("#mob_nav_trigger").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var winWidth = $(window).width(),
            docHeight = $(document).height();
        mobNav.css("minHeight", docHeight).addClass("visible_now").animate({
            left: parseInt(mobNav.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -mobNav.outerWidth() : 0
        });
        shift.animate({
          marginLeft: parseInt(shift.css('margin-left'),10) == 200 ? 0 : 200
        }).css("minWidth", winWidth);
      });
});
```

Of course I'll be refactoring the code and take some code which is repeating and convert it into a function like:

```
    if(parseInt(mobNav.css("left"), 10) == 0){
      // if is visible then hide
      mobNav.css("left", -mobNav.outerWidth());
      shift.css("margin-left", "0");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Notes

I gave it a shot, there isn't really much that I felt could be improved upon though. I'm sure performance would be better if you were using CSS3 transitions (the implementation certainly would be nicer <3 CSS3) but I assume you wanted better browser coverage.

- Ideally put your CSS in a separate file to keep your markup clean.
- I put a function around your code so that the symbols can be properly minified.
- I introduced a `menuVisible` variable which will be `false` if the menu is not showing and not in transition. The reason I did this was to simplify the conditions on scroll, resize and button click events that run every time.
- Fluent syntax for `$(window)` when hooking up events, saves converting `window` into a `jQuery` object twice.
- Refactored a little so the functions are better split up and to clean up document ready.
- Something I noticed when playing with your menu from the link you gave, it's actually not very smooth at all on my desktop if the menu is transitioning at the same time as your slideshow. I suggest you halt the animation on your slideshow when the button is pressed, that will probably make the biggest difference to how smooth the page is.

  Alternatively you could disable the slideshow all together or remove the animation when it's in the mobile media query, scrolling may suffer as a result of the slideshow animation as well.

### Code

#### HTML

```
<div id="mobNav"></div>

<div id="shift">
    content Goes Here
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#mobNav {
    background: url(images/top_bg.jpg) repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:-200px;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
}
```

#### JS

```
(function ($, window, document) {
    var mobNav, mainNav, top, shift;
    var menuVisible = false;
    
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        mobNav      = $("#mobNav");
        mainNav     = $("#mainnav");
        top         = $("#top");
        shift       = $("#shift");
        
        mobNav.html(mainNav.html());
        
        $(window).on("scroll", scroll);
                 .on("resize", hideMenu);
        $("#mob_nav_trigger").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            showMenu();
        });
    });
    
    function scroll() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300)
            top.fadeIn();
        else
            top.fadeOut();
        hideMenu();
    }
    
    function showMenu() {
        var winWidth = $(window).width(),
            docHeight = $(document).height();
        mobNav.css("minHeight", docHeight)
              .addClass("visible_now")
              .animate({ 
                  left: menuVisible ? -mobNav.outerWidth() : 0 }, 
                  function () { 
                      if (menuVisible) 
                          menuVisible = false;
              });
        shift.css("minWidth", winWidth)
             .animate({ marginLeft: menuVisible ? 0 : 200 });
        if (!menuVisible)
            menuVisible = true;
    }
    
    function hideMenu() {
        if (menuVisible) {
            mobNav.css("left", -mobNav.outerWidth());
            shift.css("margin-left", "0");
            menuVisible = false;
        }
    }
})($, window, document);
```

Comment: @tyiar thank you so much for your time.. really appreciate it. :)